# Run prerequest script to stringify body of the request

Tags: postman, stringify, postman-pre-request-script

I am using post man to send a post request with the body as form-data which contains files and text. See the image below:

[image: post request body]

I want to json.stringify the entire body but I cannot work out how to do this in a pre-request script. As an environment variable can only be one part of the  body further having files makes it more tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the problem. In postman the request is a JavaScript object. If you are trying to stringify the request, I assume you are trying to get this:

```
propertyOne=valueOne&propertyTwo=ValueTwo
```

out of this:

```
const request = {
    propertyOne: 'valueOne',
    propertyTwo: 'ValueTwo'
};
```

The simple way is just to iterate the object's properties and write into an string:

```
function stringifyRequest(object) {
    let resultString = '';
    for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            let tempString = `${property}=${object[property]}`;
            resultString = resultString ? `${resultString}&${tempString}` : tempString;
        }
    }
    return resultString
}
```

Now, if you want to get the binary of the file you are uploading, it will not be possible. As seen in [this thread](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1050):

> We don't give access to the contents of the files in pre-request
>   scripts, for a few reasons.
>
> 1. We want to delay loading file contents to right before the request
>      is sent.
> 2. The request body is not actually resolved until the pre request
>      scripts are completed. So even if we wanted to we can't give the
>      actual body of the request in pre-request scripts.

They may eventually change that, but I could not find any indications of it. One user in this thread suggests using [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/), you could check it out if fits your needs better.